# How to delete (DROP) an Access table using Jackcess

Tags: java, ms-access, ms-access-2007, jackcess

I am using Jackcess in my project to connect an MS Access database, but I couldn't find the method to delete a table.

How can I **delete** a table using Jackcess?

```
Database db = null;
try 
{
    db = Database.open(FileLocations.getCache());
    Table table = db.getTable("refNum");
    //table.delete(); //trying to achieve
}
catch (IOException ex) 
{
    Logger.getLogger(TheDatabase.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
finally 
{
    try 
    {
        db.close();
    } 
    catch (IOException ex) 
    {
        Logger.getLogger(TheDatabase.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code seems to do the trick:

```java
Database db = DatabaseBuilder.open(new File("C:/Users/Public/mdbTest.mdb")); 

Table tbl = db.getSystemTable("MSysObjects");
Cursor crsr = tbl.getDefaultCursor();

Map<String, Object> findCriteria = new HashMap<String, Object>();
findCriteria.put("Name", "refNum");
findCriteria.put("Type", (short)1);

String status = "";
if (crsr.findFirstRow(findCriteria)) {
    tbl.deleteRow(crsr.getCurrentRow());
    status = "table dropped (row deleted from MSysObjects)";
}
else {
    status = "row not found in MSysObjects";
}
System.out.println(status);

db.close();
```

Comment: FYI, use Jackcess version 2.0.3